# Solution for this inequality $a^2 - 4b + 8 > 0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I dont know where I messed up, this is what I have done:

This is the isolated x of a function 
$$x = \frac{1}{2}\biggl(\pm\sqrt{a^2 - 4 b + 8} - a - 4\biggr)$$

The root above must be positive and greater than $0$ so a function could have inflection points.

So: $a^2 - 4 b + 8 > 0$

$b$ isolated:

$b<\frac{1}{4}\ (a^2 + 8)$

And $a$ isolated:

$a> \sqrt{4b-8}$

$b$ must be $\geq 2$ so that the root above could be real

With this in mind

if $a=1$

then $b<\frac{9}{4}\ $

And here is where I dont know what's wrong because It works even if I use $b$ values greater than $\frac{9}{4}\ $

Comment: I don't understand what is your question.

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry, I was editing the question, I want to know where I messed up this inequaility

Comment: Your solution of the inequation is flawed, which results in a loss of cases. However, this appears to be irrelevant for the actual question, so I shan't be discussing this. On the other hand, you claim that $a=1$ and $b=\beta$ is a solution for some $\beta>\frac94$: can you name one? Because I've tried $\frac52$ and it does not work.

Comment: @Shai Are you looking for conditions on $a$ and $b$ such that $x>0$?

Comment: I noticed the error editing the answer, while solving the inflection points, I was using the "9/4" as if it were the value of $a$ but the value of a is always $1$. Im so sorry for wasting your time people, I'm a bit tired haha.

Comment: @Shai Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To guarantee that exist

$$\sqrt{a^2 - 4 b + 8} $$

you have to set

$$a^2 - 4 b + 8 \geq 0\implies a^2\geq4b-8$$

and consider **2 cases**

1. $$4b-8<0 \implies a^2\geq0>4b-8$$
2. $$4b-8\geq0 \implies -\sqrt{4b-8}\leq a^2\leq \sqrt{4b-8}$$

To solve
$$x = \frac{1}{2}\biggl(\pm\sqrt{a^2 - 4 b + 8} - a - 4\biggr)>0 \iff\pm\sqrt{a^2 - 4 b + 8} - a - 4>0$$

consider two cases

**CASE 1**

$$\sqrt{a^2 - 4 b + 8} - a - 4>0 \implies\sqrt{a^2 - 4 b + 8}>a + 4$$

The system to solve is

$$\begin{cases}\sqrt{a^2 - 4 b + 8}>a + 4\\ a^2 - 4 b + 8 \geq 0\end{cases}$$

If:

$a+4<0$ you only have to check that $a^2 - 4 b + 8 \geq 0$

$a+4\geq0$ you can square and the system becomes

$$\begin{cases}a^2 - 4 b + 8>a^2+8a + 16\\ a^2 - 4 b + 8 \geq 0\end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}2a+b+2<0\\ a^2 - 4 b + 8 \geq 0\end{cases}$$

**CASE 2**

$$-\sqrt{a^2 - 4 b + 8} - a - 4>0 \implies a+4<-\sqrt{a^2 - 4 b + 8}$$

The system to solve is

$$\begin{cases}a+4<-\sqrt{a^2 - 4 b + 8}\\ a^2 - 4 b + 8 \geq 0\end{cases}$$

If:

$a+4\geq0$ no solutions

$a+4<0$ you can square reversing the sign and the system becomes

$$\begin{cases}a^2+8a + 16>a^2 - 4 b + 8\\ a^2 - 4 b + 8 \geq 0\end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}2a+b+2>0\\ a^2 - 4 b + 8 \geq 0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Plot the   parabola $ y^2 = 4(x-2) $. Now the equation denotes the region outside the parabola. This is the general solution if that's what you wanted.